# Is inhibin hormone secreted by corpus luteum in females?

Tags: reproduction, endocrinology

In females, I have studied that corpus luteum secretes mostly progesterone, but some of estrogen, relaxin and inhibin too. But in some of the books they say that inhibin is not secreted by corpus luteum. Can someone please explain.

Answer (score 0):

In human females, inhibin is secreted by the granulosa cells of the primary oocyte which inhibit FSH secretion ,resulting in the stoppage of follicle maturation until activin ,again secreted by granulosa cells activate FSH activity .

Comment: I think this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: So inhibin is secreted by primary oocyte and not corpus luteum?